# reactjs run code after all elements are loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am in my first steps with react. I am running Reactjs v16.11.0

I have page which trigger the webcam (following [this mdn tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos)). So I want to call `startup` function when all elements were painted. I tried with `window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);` but it doesn't call any function.

So I tried the useEffectHook:

```
useEffect  (() => {
    startup();
  }, []);
```

But it call the startup function too soon, and there is some elments that there aren't still in the DOM because it runs asyncronous code - `video` .

My startup function is this

```
const startup= () => {
   video = document.getElementById('video');
   let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
   const photo = document.getElementById('photo') as HTMLElement;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
  .then(function(stream) {
    mediaStream = stream.getTracks()[0];
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
  });

if(video) {
  video.addEventListener('canplay', function (ev: any) {
    if (!streaming) {
      height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);
      // Firefox currently has a bug where the height can't be read from
      // the video, so we will make assumptions if this happens.
      if (isNaN(height)) {
        height = width / (4 / 3);
      }

      video.setAttribute('width', width);
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width.toString());
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height.toString());
      streaming = true;
    }
  }, false);

  //clearphoto(canvas, photo);
}
```

}

I am using functional component (instead of class component). And from what I understood componentDidMount works with class component. Am I correct?

How can accomplish to run the startup function only when every elements are in the DOM ?

EDIT: code edit in useEffect hook, noticed by Jayraj

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished following the tutorial. It was interesting to me, as well.
First of all, you can play my demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bassi-ojccj?file=/src/App.js.
To achieve the goal I used three hooks: `useRef`, `useEffect`, `useState`. Let's me explain why I have used each of them.

So, I would like to start with the `useState` hook. Before streaming, we should calculate the height of the image and canvas and set it. However, we must save the height into somewhere to get its value in our component. That's why I used the `useState` hook.

To draw `canvas` successfully I used the `useRef` hook. It allows me to access the DOM and that's why I removed calls the `getElementById` from the code as the hook is responsible for. I made the same with the video. I created the `videoRef` to access the DOM.

And the main that I called the `useEffect` hook two times. As you can see, the first `useEffect` hasn't any dependencies that's why it will be called once. It works like the `componentDidMount` method in this case. Thankfully to it, the `getUserMedia` method is called and we can set stream to the `videoRef` and afterwards the video will be started playing.
The second `useEffect` waitings for the changes of the `videoRef` property and then it starts executing.

I guess you should read about react hook more deeply to understand very well. Let's me attach the link of the documentation. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Have a good day.